# Fill private fields through returned pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++98

I have a container class:

```
class Container {
public:
    MyItem* getItem() { return mItem.get(); }
private:
    std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
};
```

I'm trying to write an `initializeContainer()` method where I use `Container.getItem()` to set `mItem`. Here are some possible approaches, with my doubts about them in comments:

```
void initialize(Conatiner& container) {
    MyItem item;
    container.getItem() = &item; // Wrong, item gets destroyed at the end of the function

    container.getItem() = new MyItem();          
    // This approach is filling my needs so far, but that doesn't necessarily
    // mean it's correct.
    // In particular, I'm not sure this approach properly removes the original item.

    // Here I try to use placement new to reuse the memory pointed to by container.getitem
    if (container.getItem()) {
        MyItem* pItem = container.getItem();
        pItem->~MyItem();
        pItem = new (pItem) MyItem();
    } // but if the pointer is null, I don't have any memory to reassign!
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to handle populating fields through a pointer? I do not have access to C++11 features or external libraries like Boost. I am also not allowed to change the interface of `Container`.

Comment: Please stop using `std::auto_ptr`, in some cases it can be dangerous, it has been deprecated since C++11 in favor of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), and `std::auto_ptr` will be removed from the C++17 standard.

Comment: Why keep it private at all if you're just going to allow modification through a public function? Anyway, what about `*container.getItem() = MyItem();`?

Comment: Also note that `getItem` returns the stored pointer *by value* so doing any assignment with `getItem` in the left-hand-side will not work. Possibly doing e.g. `*container.getItem() = MyItem()` should work though. It *does* bypass the whole "ownership" model of the smart pointers though.

Comment: As for me, method name `getItem` associates with getting the `Item`, not with its modification. Why not to write `setItem` for changing the `Item`?

Comment: How about using move semantics: `std::unique_ptr<MyItem> p2(new MyItem);
p1 = std::move(p2);`

Comment: One question per question please. Not four.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Because it is valid for `container.getItem()` to be null.

Comment: @JETM Then do a null check and take no action in that case. However, that still doesn't answer why you shouldn't just make it public (which makes knowing _how to modify it_ very simple).

Comment: @JamesAdkison The short answer is that I'm not in a position to redesign things on that scope. But it is a public field in a derived class, and I need to populate it through a pointer to the base Container that doesn't have the field. Trust me, I know how ugly this sounds.  Is there a way to populate the field if the method returns null?

Comment: @JETM: now you are asking a completely different question that is not related to the code of your question. If you have an object of a derived class that has a public member, and you have a pointer to that object's base class, then simply type-cast that pointer to the derived class so you can access its public member normally. If you know for sure the base class points at a specific derived class, use `static_cast`, otherwise use `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initializeContainer()` simply does not have access to set the `Container::mItem` member through normal channels.  And you can't use `Container::getItem()` to provide that access, because it returns the `MyItem*` pointer that `mItem` holds, and you can't reach `mItem` from that pointer.

You need to change `Container` to allow access to `mItem`, either by:

1. giving `Container` a public method that sets `mItem`, then have `initializeContainer()` call that method:

   ```
   class Container {
   private:
       std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
   public:
       MyItem* getItem() { return mItem.get(); }
       void setItem(const MyItem &item) { mItem.reset(new MyItem(item)); }
   };

   void initialize(Container& container) {
       MyItem item;
       container.setItem(item);
   }
   ```
2. declaring `initializeContainer()` as a `friend` of `Container` so it can access `private` members directly:

   ```
   class Container {
   private:
       std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
   public:
       MyItem* getItem() { return mItem.get(); }

       friend void initialize(Container&);
   };

   void initialize(Container& container) {
       container.mItem.reset(new MyItem);
   }
   ```
3. Getting rid of `initializeContainer()` altogether and give `Container` a public initialization method instead:

   ```
   class Container {
   private:
       std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
   public:
       void init() { mItem.reset(new MyItem); }
       MyItem* getItem() { return mItem.get(); }
   };

   Container c;
   c.init();
   ```

> Is there an idiomatic way to handle populating fields through a pointer?

Not the way you are attempting to do it, no.  You are trying to use a pointer that is not related to the `Container` object itself, just held by it.  So you can't use that pointer to access members of the `Container` object, since it does not point at the `Container` object to begin with.

> I am also not allowed to change the interface of Container.

Well, then you are out of luck, because what you are attempting to do requires an interface change.  Unless you use an ugly pointer hack, eg:

```
class Container {
private:
    std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
public:
    MyItem* getItem() { return mItem.get(); }
};

void initialize(Container& container) {
    unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&container);
    std::auto_ptr<MyItem> *ap = reinterpret_cast<std::auto_ptr<MyItem>*>(p + offsetof(Container, mItem));
    ap->reset(new MyItem);
}
```

---

On the other hand, if your intention is not to change `mItem` itself, but simply to (re-)initialize the `MyItem` object that `mItem` is already holding, you *can* use `getItem()` for that, but only if the `MyItem` object has been created beforehand:

```
void initialize(Container &container) {
    MyItem *item = container.getItem();
    if (item) *item = MyItem();
}
```

Which you can ensure by not allowing `mItem` to hold a null pointer in the first place:

```
class Container {
private:
    std::auto_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
public:
    Container() : mItem(new MyItem) {}
    Container(const Container &src) : mItem(new MyItem(src.getItem())) {}
    Container& operator=(const Container &rhs) { mItem.reset(new MyItem(rhs.getItem())); return *this; }

    MyItem& getItem() { return *mItem.get(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*The following implies modification of class `Container` and not-null pointer.*

E.g., using plain pointer (not `auto`), and a return by reference:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyItem{
private:
    int a;
public:
    ~MyItem(){std::cout<<"My item destroyed!\n";}
    MyItem(int _a):a(_a){};
    int getValue(){return a;}
};

class Container {
public:
    MyItem & getItem() { return *(mItem); }
private:
    MyItem* mItem;
};

void initialize(Container& container) {
    std::cout<<"New item\n";
    MyItem* p2=new MyItem(25);
    std::cout<<"Getting item\n";
    MyItem &p1 = container.getItem();
    std::cout<<"Copying\n";
    p1=*p2; // should define your own operator = for complex MyItem type
    delete p2;
    std::cout<<"New item\n";
    MyItem* p3=new MyItem(5);
    std::cout<<"Copying\n";
    p1=*p3;
    delete p3;
}

int main()
{
    Container c;
    initialize(c);
    std::cout<<c.getItem().getValue()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
New item
Getting item
Copying
My item destroyed!
New item
Copying
My item destroyed!
5
```

With pointer instead of reference (changing only relevant code blocks):

```
    ...
    MyItem* getItem() { return mItem; }
    ...
    MyItem *p1 = container.getItem();
    std::cout<<"Copying\n";
    *p1=*p2;
    ... (the same with p3)
    ...
    std::cout<<c.getItem()->getValue()<<std::endl;
```

---

The answer below uses `C++11`.

You can access `unique_ptr`through reference, then use move semantics to 
change the value of the object to which the smart pointer points.

An example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyItem{
private:
    int a;
public:
    ~MyItem(){std::cout<<"My item destroyed!\n";}    
    MyItem(int _a):a(_a){};
    int getValue(){return a;}
};

class Container {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyItem> & getItem() { return mItem; }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyItem> mItem;
};

void initialize(Container& container) {
    std::unique_ptr<MyItem> p2(new MyItem(5));
    std::unique_ptr<MyItem> &p1 = container.getItem();
    std::cout<<"Copying\n";
    p1 = std::move(p2);
    std::unique_ptr<MyItem> p3(new MyItem(20));
    std::cout<<"Copying\n";
    p1 = std::move(p3);
}

int main()
{
    Container c;
    initialize(c);
    std::cout<<c.getItem()->getValue()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```